# Error when compiling using makefile

Tags: c++, class, makefile, linked-list, compilation

I'm working on a personal project which has 2 cpp files (main.cpp and linkedList.cpp) and 2 header files (linkedList.h and node.h). Below are the #include statements for each of those files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedList.h"
```

linkedList.cpp:

```
#include "linkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
```

node.h:

```
#include <string>
```

linkedList.h:

```
#include "node.h"
```

I use this makefile to copile and run this program:

```
all: hello

hello: main.o node.h linkedList.h linkedList.o
    g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o hello main.o linkedList.o

main.o: main.cpp linkedList.h linkedList.o
    g++ -c main.cpp

linkedList.o: linkedList.cpp linkedList.h
    g++ -c linkedList.cpp

clean:
    rm -f hello *.o
```

This gives an error saying "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64." I looked it up and found out it's because files aren't linked properly. Is that really the problem? I used this makefile before and it worked fine

EDIT: This is the error from terminal:

```
  "linkedList::print()", referenced from:
      _main in main-9cc99d.o
  "linkedList::size()", referenced from:
      _main in main-9cc99d.o
```

Comment: You used it before something and it worked and it stopped working. What  you did inbetween?

Comment: It wasn't used for the same program so files were different but I only really changed the names so i dont know why it stopped working

Comment: Does the error message not tell you which symbols are undefined? What if you prune the code in `main.cpp` until the error vanishes (or you reach `int main(){return 0;}`)?

Comment: Note `-Wall` and `-std=c++11` will have much more effect on compile steps than link steps.

Comment: We can only guess what's wrong here. At the very least, we would need to know what symbols the linker complains about. At best, you reduce it to a few very small files that show the same problem and post all their complete contents as a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the post to include the error I get in terminal

Comment: Why are you including LinkedList.h in main and in LinkedList.cpp? Also, are you trying to get one executable? Or two?

Comment: Just one executable which is main. I get this error when I try to compile main

Comment: Your dependencies are a bit strange. Object files only depend on source files (`.cpp` and `.h`), not on other object files. And executables only depend on object files, not on header files. Anyway, the message of the linker is clear: your `main` invokes methods `print` and `size` of `LinkedList` but the linker couldn't find them.